# Grouping Tokeninput

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I'm using [Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) to create a box that allows only pre-determined results from the database.

However, one thing this plug-in is missing is the ability to group the suggestions. So I could have a list like this;

```
Sausages
  Mettwurst
  Bratwurst
Companies
  Wurth
  Wu Tang
  Altawusta
```

The category labels would not be selectable, only informative.

I've already prepared the JSON to send an extra key `category` that contains the plaintext name of the category; i.e., every suggestion in the Companies block has `category: "Companies"` in their object. I thought grouping the suggestions would be easy this way.

Are there any modifications or alternative plug-ins that would achieve what I'm looking for?

If not, how would I go about modifying Tokeninput to support these changes? I see their Github has an issue listed for this, but no response.

Answer (score 1):

Will the built-in jQuery UI autocomplete not work for you? It supports categories -

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories

EDIT -

Whoops, meant to make this a comment.. :(

Comment: I really like the tokenizing effect of Tokeninput; as in, once it's selected, it's "locked" unless you delete it by clicking X. Autocomplete just suggests things, but lets you send whatever text you want anyway; unless there's a setting/mod to stop this?